# Extracting xml node from soap response

Tags: oracle, plsql, xml-parsing

Following is part of a soap response,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<idc:QuickSearchResponse xmlns:idc="http://www.stellent.com/Search/">
<idc:QuickSearchResult>
<idc:SearchResults>
<idc:dID>127649</idc:dID>
<idc:dRevisionID>1</idc:dRevisionID>
<idc:dDocName>10026726</idc:dDocName>
<idc:dDocTitle>approved Milestone fpr Porject 4176</idc:dDocTitle>
<idc:dDocType>IT</idc:dDocType>
<idc:dDocAuthor>Portfolio</idc:dDocAuthor>
```

I want to extract the node `dID` from it. I have tried using the function `extractValue` as follows,

```
select extractValue(xml1, '//idc:dID', 'xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:idc="http://www.stellent.com/Search/"') AS l_value from dual;
```

But it does not work. How do i extract the node `dID`?

Comment: You are missing language tag you are trying to write code with.

Comment: I am trying to extract the node through pl/sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`XMLTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm#CIHGGHFB):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  2  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  3     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  4     <idc:QuickSearchResponse xmlns:idc="http://www.stellent.com/Search/">
  5        <idc:QuickSearchResult>
  6           <idc:SearchResults>
  7              <idc:dID>127649</idc:dID>
  8              <idc:dRevisionID>1</idc:dRevisionID>
  9              <idc:dDocName>10026726</idc:dDocName>
 10              <idc:dDocTitle>approved Milestone fpr Porject 4176</idc:dDocTitle>
 11              <idc:dDocType>IT</idc:dDocType>
 12              <idc:dDocAuthor>Portfolio</idc:dDocAuthor>
 13           </idc:SearchResults>
 14        </idc:QuickSearchResult>
 15     </idc:QuickSearchResponse>
 16     </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 17  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>' xml FROM dual)
 18  SELECT did
 19    FROM data,
 20         xmltable(XMLNamespaces ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
 21                                  AS "SOAP-ENV",
 22                                 'http://www.stellent.com/Search/' AS "idc"),
 23                  '/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/idc:QuickSearchResponse/idc:QuickSearchResult/idc:SearchResults'
 24                  PASSING XMLTYPE(xml)
 25                  COLUMNS
 26                    did NUMBER PATH 'idc:dID');

       DID
----------
    127649
```

Both [`ExtractValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm#SQLRF06173) and [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions060.htm#SQLRF00640) are deprecated in 11g.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to construct the soap xml XPath in Pl/Sql code. For example when calling DBMS_XMLDOM.GetNodeValue() method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in Pl/SQL then construct a DBMS_XMLDOM.DomDocument from your CLOB or BLOB XML message. You can use the below method.

> DBMS_XMLPARSER.getDocument()

Then you can use the below method to get the node value from SOAP response

```
FUNCTION Get_Node_Value_From_Doc(
   v_Doc         IN DBMS_XMLDOM.DomDocument) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   v_Clob CLOB;
   v_RootNode DBMS_XMLDOM.DomNode;
   v_Value VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN       
   v_RootNode := DBMS_XMLDOM.MakeNode(XmlDom.GetDocumentElement(v_Doc));
   v_Value := DBMS_XMLDOM.GetNodeValue(XslProcessor.SelectSingleNode(v_RootNode,
   '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetLiveAnalysisIDSResponse[1]/AnalysisIDs[1]/guid[1]/text()'
   ,'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="https://www.testkid.net/"'));  
   RETURN v_Value;
END Get_Node_Value_From_Doc;
```

You may use other methods from DBMS_XMLDOM package but providing the correct namespace is important. Also note the way XPATH is constructed. For more info on
creating XPATH Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E16659_03/xdb04cre.htm).